# How to fetch data from ListColumn[String] in Phantom using contains condition

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, phantom-dsl, phantom-types

I have a Cassandra table `Department` with columns `name_list extends ListColumn[String]` and `id extends StringColumn with PartitionKey`.

I want to fetch **id** where the requested ***name*** is present in **name_list**.

I tried using *in* operator `select(_.id).where(name in name_list)` but it is not working.

Another query I tried `select(_.id).where(_.name_list contains name)` but it is also not working for me.

```
 def getByName(name: String) = {
    select(_.id, _.name_list).where(_.name_list contains name)   
}
```

Is there any way to solve this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SetColumn as the type for you column then you will be able to use the `contains` method. Use this

`name_list extends SetColumn[String]`

then this will work fine

```
def getByName(name: String) = {
    select(_.id, _.name_list).where(_.name_list contains name)   
}
```

Thanks